# how to change site width in wordpress

Tags: css, wordpress

I'm trying to change my site width to full-width, but the option to change it in the wordpress custumizer is disabled.

What do I need to change in the css file in order to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've checked the site link you mentioned.
You need to add this css in the style.css file on the theme root to make the layout fullwidth.

```
.layout {
  width: 100% !important;
}
```

Comment: thanks, unfortunately it didnt worked for me.

Comment: I have just tested this answer and it definitely works. Try clearing your browser cache and inspecting the `.layout` element in your browsers developer console to see if the style change is actually being applied.

Comment: Exactly. I have tested before adding the css here. It is working. If you have cache plugin, Please disable that also.

Answer (score 1):

You need to change layout div width 88% to 100%. Hope it's helpful to you.

Comment: i didnt find this parameter, where can i find it?

Comment: you need to add this script in footer section jQuery('.layout').css('width','100%');

Comment: if any issue please let me know.